# given a definition of node, calculate the sum of the nodes in binary tree

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, treenode

```
class Node{ 
  int value; 
  List<Node> childNodes;
}
```

Above is the definition of the Node, and I have no idea how to implement the sum of the binary tree.

```
public class TreeNode {
  int val;
  TreeNode left;
  TreeNode right;

  TreeNode(int x) {
    val = x;
  }
}
```

However, I can understand this version of node and the sum of nodes of binary tree can be implemented by recursion.

---

```
public static int sumTree(Node root) {
    int sum = 0;
    if (root == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    // Line 1
    for (int i = 0; i < root.childNodes.size(); i++) {
        sum = sum + root.childNodes.get(i).value + sumTree(root.childNodes.get(i));
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Actually, this is a tree instead of binary tree. This is my code

Comment: did you try anything by yourself? Show us the code you have tried by yourself.

Comment: I am still trying and there are a lot of bugs, I will post my code soonly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public int sum(Node root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return 0;
    } else if ( root.childNodes == null) {
        return root.value;
    }

    int sum = root.value;
    for ( Node child : root.childNodes ) {
        sum += sum(child);
    } 
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the nodes in the tree is: value of node + sum of left tree + sum of right tree.

Therefore:

```
public static int sum(TreeNode node) {
    if(node == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return node.getVal() + sum(node.getLeft()) + sum(node.getRight());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is based on the second definition of the Node, how about the first one (node with list of childs)?